# Deleting images from live server in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel-7

Been stuck on this one for a while...  I'm trying to delete images from the public folder on my live server, when testing on local server it works fine, images are saving to the appropriate folder when testing live but not deleting.

I have tried various methods mentioned on other similar stackoverflow questions such as

```
public function deleteImages($recipe_id) {

        if (file_exists(public_path() . "/assets/img/recipes/" . $recipe_id . "_square.jpg")) {
            unlink(public_path() . "/assets/img/recipes/" . $recipe_id . "_square.jpg");
        }
}
```

and

```
 File::delete(public_path() . "/assets/img/recipes/" . $recipe_id . "_square.jpg");
```

but the image is not deleting.

also ran the code

```
if (file_exists(public_path() . "/assets/img/recipes/" . $recipe_id . "_square.jpg")) {
            dd('file exists');
}
```

so I know the path is correct.  Would this be a permission issue on the server side rather than a code issue?

Answer (score 0):

In `config/filesystems.php`

```
'disk' => [
    'public_assets' => [
        'driver' => 'local',
        'root'   => public_path() . '/assets',
        'url' => public_path() . '/assets'
    ],
]
```

Upload:

```
$path = $request->file('file')->storeAs(
    'recipes',
     $filename,
    'public_assets'
);
```

Delete:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

Storage::disk('public_assets')->delete($path);
```

Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/filesystem

Comment: Getting server 500 error now

```production.ERROR: unlink(/home/forge/smathletic.com/storage/assets/img/recipes/36_square.jpg): No such file or directory {"userId":1,"exception":"[object] (ErrorException(code: 0): unlink(/home/forge/smathletic.com/storage/assets/img/recipes/36_square.jpg): No such file or directory at /home/forge/smathletic.com/app/Http/Controllers/RecipeController.php:332)```



image is saved in app/public/assets/img/recipes/

with this change it is now trying to delete from

/storage/assets/img/recipes/

Comment: Use `Storage::disk('public_assets')->delete($path);` instead of `unlink`. 
Save assets in `public` folder instead of `app` folder

Comment: ```Storage::disk('public_assets')->delete($path);```
is the function i used and produced the above error.  image file is already saved in the public folder which is why i am now getting the above error.  I don't think it is a coding issue i think this must be related to server read write privileges.  Shouldn't matter if i use php unlink or storage / file delete laravel functions.